# In Swift how can I reference a UILabel variable using a String parameter passed to a function?

Tags: ios, string, swift, int, uilabel

In Swift is there a way to assign variables by referencing a String parameter passed to a function?

My goal is to write a generic function that allows me to update a UILabel's text based on its String parameter. Specifically, the function should find the UILabel by matching its variable name to the String parameter it received.

When I attempt to join two strings when assigning the value of a variable I get the following errors: 'String' is not convertible to 'Int' and 'String' is not convertible to 'UILabel.'

Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Setup variables
    var appleCounter = 0, appleFarms = 1
    var orangeCounter = 0, orangeFarms = 1
    var grapeCounter = 0, grapeFarms = 1

    // Setup labels
    @IBOutlet weak var appleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var orangeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var grapeLabel: UILabel!

    // Function to update label
    func updateFruitLabel(fruitString: String) {

        let fruitCount: Int = (fruitString + "Counter") // error: 'String' is not convertible to 'Int'
        let fruitFarms: Int = (fruitString + "Farms") // error: 'String' is not convertible to 'Int'
        let fruitLabel: UILabel = (fruitString + "Label") // error: 'String' is not convertible to 'UILabel'

        fruitLabel.text = "\(fruitString)s: \(fruitCount), \(fruitString) farms: \(fruitFarms)"
    }

    // Setup buttons
    // Increment fruit count and call update label function
    @IBAction func appleTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        appleCounter++
        updateFruitLabel("apple")
    }

    @IBAction func orangeTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        orangeCounter++
        updateFruitLabel("orange")
    }

    @IBAction func grapeTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        grapeCounter++
        updateFruitLabel("grape")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a Enums & switch. Here's some code that should work for you:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum fruit {
        case apple
        case orange
        case grape
    }

    // Setup variables
    var appleCounter = 0, appleFarms = 1
    var orangeCounter = 0, orangeFarms = 1
    var grapeCounter = 0, grapeFarms = 1

    // Setup labels
    @IBOutlet weak var appleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var orangeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var grapeLabel: UILabel!

    // Function to update label
    func updateFruit(fruitSelected: fruit) {

        switch fruitSelected {
            case .apple: appleLabel.text = "\(++appleCounter)"
            case .orange: orangeLabel.text = "\(++orangeCounter)"
            case .grape: grapeLabel.text = "\(++grapeCounter)"
        }
    }

    // Setup buttons
    // Increment fruit count and call update label function
    @IBAction func appleTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        updateFruit(fruit.apple)
    }

    @IBAction func orangeTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        updateFruit(fruit.orange)
    }

    @IBAction func grapeTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       updateFruit(fruit.grape)
    }
}
```

OR even more simply:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Setup variables
    var appleCounter = 0, appleFarms = 1
    var orangeCounter = 0, orangeFarms = 1
    var grapeCounter = 0, grapeFarms = 1

    // Setup labels
    @IBOutlet weak var appleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var orangeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var grapeLabel: UILabel!

    // Setup buttons
    // Increment fruit count and call update label function
    @IBAction func appleTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        appleLabel.text = "\(++appleCounter)"
    }

    @IBAction func orangeTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        orangeLabel.text = "\(++orangeCounter)"
    }

    @IBAction func grapeTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       grapeLabel.text = "\(++grapeCounter)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jeff-ziligy, I'll look into it. Another problem I'm bumping into is that I want the UILabel text to contain and update several variables. So, my goal is to abstract the update code into a generic function that will be able to update the variables related to the fruit name.

Comment: several variables into one string works easily too: appleLabel.text = "\\(appleFarms) farms sold \\(appleCounter) apples"

Answer (score 0):

Normal practice would be to use an NSDictionary which maps the labels to the counters and labels, something like:

```
@{
     @"apple":{@"counter":0, @"Farms":1, @"label":appleLabel}
     @"grape":{@"counter":0, @"Farms":1, @"label":grapeLabel}
     @"orange":{@"counter":0, @"Farms":1, @"label":orangeLabel}
 }
```

Then you can pass in @"apple" and get fruitDictionary[@"label"] or fruitDictionary[@"counter"] ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, RobP. I think your answer may be related to ObjectiveC instead of Swift because the syntax doesn't work. However, there may be some helpful ideas here.

Comment: Agreed, the syntax for literals is different but the principle/pattern is the same. Rather than a `switch` statement that requires you to add more code for each new case, define a mapping from string labels to the counters and labels. Then if you add/remove labels or change their names, you just edit the map and the code does not have to change.